# General Error Distribution

Tags: matlab, distribution

Do You know if it's available in Matlab a tool to estimate the moments of a GED distribution via maximum likelihood estimation?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

try the `mle` command or the code on this page
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/examples/modelling-data-with-the-generalized-extreme-value-distribution.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but ged is different from gev.